# Django development server showing Error 61 Connection Refused with Redis

Tags: django, redis, channel

I am trying to follow the tutorial on read the docs for Django Channels. In the `settings.py` file I am trying to change the inmemory BACKEND to the redis backend with the following code:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "chan.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

However, the moment I do this, the console which is running the `runserver` command shows the following error:

```
ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you type `redis-cli` in your terminal, does it allows you to establish connection? `ping` command, maybe? And if it's 0k, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`.

Comment: No. It says command not found. But in the shell I can do `import redis`, `print redis.Redis("localhost")` which gives me `Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>`.

Comment: You should reinstall redis from guide posted in answer than. It's abnormal behavior, that `redis-cli ` is not found, 'cause it's a part of a standard dist.

Comment: It seems likely that you haven't actually installed the redis server.

Comment: I did `pip install asgi_redis`. I think it installs redis for me because I've tried doing `pip install redis` later but it says that the requirement is already installed. I am doing all this within a virtualenv. Am I missing something?

Comment: All that's doing is installing the redis client library. The server is not Python and can't be installed via pip. Get it [here](http://redis.io/download).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please make sure if redis is installed on your system and it is running.
To check if redis is running use

```
 redis-cli
```

then it will take you to redis console, then if you type `ping` it will return `PONG` if redis is running or not.

If you don't have redis in your system, please visit [Redis Quick Start.](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart)

For Mac OS X: Go to terminal and type `brew install redis`.

Comment: I did `pip install asgi_redis` and it installed Redis inside my virtualenv. Should I install from source like it says in the Redis official website?

Comment: It is not to be installed in virtualenv, it is to be installed over as root, try
`wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz`

`tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz`

`cd redis-stable`

`make`

`redis-server`

Answer (score 5):

This is worked for me:

```
redis-server
```

That's simple

Comment: ... but why does it work? it worked for me as well